Is my extented LUKS partition encrypted?
I added a second NVME on my computer and extended my encrypted LVM volume. I used the following commands to extend it :
sudo pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1            << New disk
sudo vgextend castel-vg /dev/nvme0n1
sudo lvm lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/castel-vg/root
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/castel--vg-root

The partition is well extended and all works fine, but now if I look the lsblk result :
lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme1n1                   259:0    0  3.6T  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1               259:1    0  512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2               259:2    0  488M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme1n1p3               259:3    0  3.6T  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt       254:0    0  3.6T  0 crypt 
    ├─castel--vg-root     254:1    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /
    └─castel--vg-swap_1   254:2    0  976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
nvme0n1                   259:4    0  3.6T  0 disk  
└─castel--vg-root         254:1    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /

The last two lines are giving me a doubt that the partition castel--vg-root on the drive nvme0n1 isn't using the LUKS encryption layer. Is there any way to confirm or not that the extended partition is well encrypted ?

Yes, while nvme0n1p3 is an encrypted volume (see TYPE column), nvme0n1 is not encrypted.
Apart from encryption, it's ridiculous to have a root volume of 7 TB. It's a sign of unwise space management.
